# Re-install Ubuntu 20.04 LTE

Tags: 20.04, reinstall

We have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTE on a laptop (single boot) around 6-10 months ago and now it failed to boot.
We try to reinstall system only, that is keep all data on the laptop, but during re-install, we have option to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS alongside Ubuntu 20.04.3 LT (see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EQQd.jpg)).
Partly, because we would like to re-install Ubuntu, not to have two versions on the hard drive, partly because we have no space for two versions, any suggestions on how we can re-install Ubuntu would be appreciated. Thanks.
Zoltan

Comment: First, boot from the installation media (USB/DVD) and use the Try Ubuntu option and copy all your important data to a second external USB drive before you try anything. Keeping a backup of all your data is essential. Then you can any other options you want.

Comment: You're missing some details that I'd consider. You've not stated if you're asking about a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server system, or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop system.  If it's the latter, you can re-install rather easily and have the re-install not lose any data and re-install the *manually installed* packages you'd added where from Ubuntu repositories. Do you use encryption?  have a server or desktop system?  any server apps?  how tight with disk space were you (ie. have space available on your / partition) etc.  I last did this yesterday as part of QA-testing for 22.04.1 to confirm it still works..

Comment: I'd explore why the system failed to boot first, so the re-install will not suffer the same fate.. but as I'm involved in QA-test (*Quality Assurance*) I perform the type of install I think of as "*Upgrade via re-install*" (Lubuntu call it "*Install using existing partition*") weekly on some systems instead of normal upgrades.. as it (1) upgrades packages, and (2) performs the QA-test install so we know that still works on future releases; ie. the 22.04.1 ISO I used hasn't been released yet, also done with *kinetic* (22.10) & 20.04.5 (*next to be released for focal*). It's great for desktops

Comment: If what I describe is what you're after, I've written up a description at https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743 intended for QA-testers (not end-users). It's the lack of format that triggers this type of install, and works with any Ubuntu ISO using `ubiquity` or `calamares` as the installer (ie. desktop releases excluding older *di* I've not tested it with; it may actually work there too but I've never looked). I've also documented it on this site ~30 times too but I'd not want to find it..  (*often only in comments*). Works with Ubuntu and *flavors*

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It is a desktop (Lenovo laptop)
We tried to backup from Live (Try Ubuntu), but unfortunately that could not write USB, which can be is strange and probably a different problem. We normally backup data, so now we check if we missed anything, before re-install.
Recovery, when there are two partitions (system and data), should work (line on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sD7Rp8Jt1rE), but unfortunately we have everything on one partition – next time we will separate the two.

Comment: We also tried to find the reason and it seems it is a bug, quite similar to this:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/bug-unable-to-handle-page-fault-4175696212/

Comment: FYI:  Re-install without being destructive is just as easy in my opinion with a single partition as two (*with Ubuntu Desktop installs*),  the primary benefit of a /home being separate is to allow replacing Ubuntu with another OS that doesn't have the flexibility found in `calamares` or `ubiquity` for Ubuntu Desktop installs (technically it's not the installer; but Ubuntu scripts the installer uses)

Comment: If it's a bug, it belongs on a Bug tracking site & not this support Q&A site.  Please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Although I have seen many reassurances of how easy to do it, I have not found any step-by-step instructions or preferably a YouTube video.
To report a bug, I should create another account and as I am luckily not a regular Linux user, I rather do not waste time on that.

Comment: I've written answers on this site many times on this re-install so I know they exist (*but as I've written >650 answers here I don't want to write yet another on a topic I've written about 3+ times in answers & ~30+ times in comments; have you looked for any?*). I've provided a link already where I describe it for the purpose of QA-testers; that link provided as that was easier for me to find. This isn't a youtube site; so providing youtube links is off-topic for SE/Ubuntu anyway.  The type of install, your packages esp. 3rd party involved impact results; FYI testing has no 3rd party packages.